# Profiles and Permission Sets

Tags: community, profile, permission-sets

Users are allowed to view all data within our Org, with one exception. Users in Region X are not allow to view leads from other regions but then can view any leads within their region.  How do I set this up?

Thanks,

Comment: You could probably use role hierarchy for this.

Comment: And org-wide defaults, and sharing rules - but definitely not profiles or permission sets ...

Comment: Thank you Luke and John.  This is my plan after reading your proposals.  Set the OWD on Lead object to Public/RW and enforce role hierarchy.  Then put Region X under the rest of the All Regions (Excluding Region X) in the role hierarchy setup.  Do you think this will works?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your comment:

No. As you go along the different levels of security you can only widen access, you cannot restrict it. OWD is the first level, if you have Lead as public/rw at that level everyone can rw Leads regardless of role hierarchy or anything else.

Set the OWD to be private and go from there.

Comment: As @Force Hero suggested, I set OWD to private, created two groups and added sharing rules.  It works like a charm.

Comment: I've found this very small and quick article helpful in understanding some gotchas regarding role hierarchy, profiles, permission sets, sharing rules, etc. https://opfocus.com/configuring-salesforce-profiles-tips-i-wish-someone-told-me-from-the-start/

Comment: And also this one which is a bit larger but very comprehensive and clear https://eltoroit.herokuapp.com/Blog.app?page=SalesforceSecurityWhatEveryDeveloperMustKnow